# PIC18F2550 sleep and wake up

Tags: c, pic

We have succeeded in putting the PIC to sleep, but we also want to wake it using an external interrupt from our side. However, the PIC is going in an infinite loop and is waking itself up.How can we resolve this problem? The code is as follows:

```
#include<p18f2550.h>
#include<delays.h>

void main()
{

    TRISB = 0x20;
    TRISA = 0x00;
    TRISC = 0x00;

    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
    INTCONbits.RBIE = 1;

    while(1)       
    {
        PORTA=0xff;
        Delay10KTCYx(500);

        PORTA=0x00;
        Delay10KTCYx(500);

        PORTA=0xff;
        Delay10KTCYx(500);

        PORTA=0x00;
        Delay10KTCYx(500);

        PORTA=0xff;
        Delay10KTCYx(500);

        _asm
        sleep
        _endasm
     }
}

#pragma interrupt ISR
void ISR(void)
{   
    if (INTCONbits.RBIF == 1)
    {
        if(PORTBbits.RB5 == 1)
           PORTA = 0x00;

    }
    INTCONbits.RBIF = 0;
}
```

Comment: @navinika add more relevant tags, you might get any help

Comment: Did you disable the watchdog timer? otherwise the watchdog interrupt will wake it from sleep.

Comment: How are your config bits setted?

Comment: You may need to disable all interrupts except for a select few.